# Yii large SQL queries consumes a large amount of memory

Tags: php, apache, yii

I am using Yii 1.1.14 with php 5.3 on centos 6 and I am using CDbCommand to fetch data from a very large table, the result set is ~90,000 records over 10 columns I am exporting it to a csv file and the file size is about 15MB, 
the script always crashed without any error messages and only after some research I figured out that I need to raise the memory_limit in php.ini in order to be able to execute the script successfully.
The only problem is that for a successful execution I had to raise the memory limit to 512MB(!) which is a lot! and if 10 users will be executing the same script my server will not respond very well...

I was wondering if anyone might know of a way to reduce memory consumption on sql queries with Yii?
I know I can split the query to multiple queries using limits and offsets, but it just doesn't seem logical that a 15MB query will consume 512MB.

Here is the code:

```
set_time_limit(0);
$connection = new CDbConnection($dsn,$username,$password);
$command = $connection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM TEST_DATA');
$result = $command->queryAll(); //this is where the script crashes
print_r($result);
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure the problem isnt at the database? If its a very large query you might be timing PHP out rather than exhausting its memory. I assume you are on MySQL. Perhaps try some indexing to speed it up otherwise you are stuck with limit and offset or migration to a NoSQL solution

Comment: So you think that if something takes up 15MB when written down to a file, it must allocate the same amount of memory when transforming that to data structures of a language that hold the information? But to answer your question with what you already (correctly) guessed - use LIMIT and OFFSET. Do not load everything at once. Calculate how many rows you have and perform your operation on 5k rows before moving to next 5k rows - until you finish all 90k.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies! @mike miller, There shouldn't be a timing issue because the script fails very quickly ~5 seconds, and I have set the time limit to 0..

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using [readAll](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbDataReader#readAll) that will returns all the rows in a single array (the real memory problem is here), you should simply use a foreach loop (take a look at [CDbDataReader](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbDataReader)), e.g. :

```
$command = $connection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM TEST_DATA');
$rows = $command->query();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{

}
```

**EDIT** : Using LIMIT

```
$count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST_DATA')->queryScalar();
$maxRows = 1000:
$maxPages = ceil($count / $maxRows);

for ($i=0;$i<$maxPages;$i++)
{
    $offset = $i * $maxRows;
    $rows = $connection->createCommand("SELECT * FROM TEST_DATA LIMIT $offset,$maxRows")->query();
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
      // Here your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this method is very good, using your example I was able to create a 16MB file with approx ~110,000 records, so this is a ~20% improvement! but still the script fails at $rows = $command->query(); when trying to get more records... any ideas?